# cx_Freeze Build of Tkinter Application Extremely Buggy

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I recently created a small game using `tkinter` (python version 3.6.1) and froze it using `cx_Freeze`. The game has four buttons: an undo button, a restart button, a "find legal moves" button, and a "find best move button". The "find best move" button uses a `shelve` database to find the best move for the first three turns and a recursive function that traverses the move tree on the fly for the fourth turn and up. My code disables the buttons when they should not be used.

I made sure to include the necessary DLLs in the setup script and I was able to run the executable without errors. However, three of the buttons are disabled until the fourth turn (when the recursive function begins to be used) and the application is extremely buggy in many other ways. However, it works perfectly when I run the unfrozen version.

I honestly don't know what code snippets I would need to provide to you guys, as this issue has me utterly at a loss. The only clue I have is that the `pyc` files in the build differ in size from the unfrozen app. I know this is rather vague, but I do not know what specifics would be useful to give. Any help, if possible, would be greatly appreciated.

"Find best move" method:

```
def _find_best_move(self):
    """Finds best move possible for current game."""
    if len(self.game.moves) <= 3:
        with shelve.open("paths") as db:
            best_paths = db[str(self.game.moves)]
            best_path = choice(best_paths)
    else:
        self.path_finder(self.game)
        best_path = self.path_finder.best_path
    best_move = best_path[len(self.game.moves)]
    best_move = (__class__._add_offset(best_move[0]), best_move[1])
    return best_move
```

Updates Button State:

```
def update_gui(self):
    """Updates GUI to reflect current game conditions."""
    legal_moves = self.game.find_legal_moves()
    if self.game.moves:
        self.undo_btn["state"] = "!disabled"
        self.restart_btn["state"] = "!disabled"
        self.best_move_btn["state"] = "!disabled"
    else:
        self.undo_btn["state"] = "disabled"
        self.restart_btn["state"] = "disabled"
    if legal_moves:
        self.show_moves_btn["state"] = "!disabled"
    else:
        self.show_moves_btn["state"] = "disabled"
    if legal_moves and self.game.moves:
        self.best_move_btn["state"] = "!disabled"
    else:
        self.best_move_btn["state"] = "disabled"
```

My `__init__` file:

```
initpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(os.path.join(initpath, "data"))
```

`PathFinder` class (traverses move tree on the fly):

```
class PathFinder:
    """Provides methods to find move paths that meet various criteria.

    Designed to be called after the player makes a move.
    """

    _game = None
    best_path = None
    best_score = None

    def __call__(self, game):
        """Call self as function."""
        if not game:
            self._game = DummyGame()
        elif not isinstance(game, DummyGame):
            self._game = DummyGame(game)
        else:
            self._game = game
        moves = self._game.moves
        self.possible_paths = dict.fromkeys(range(1,9))
        root = Node(moves[-1])
        self._find_paths(root)
        self._find_paths.cache_clear()
        found_scores = [score for score in self.possible_paths.keys() if
                        self.possible_paths[score]]
        self.best_score = min(found_scores)
        self.best_path = self.possible_paths[self.best_score]

    @lru_cache(None)
    def _find_paths(self, node):
        """Finds possible paths and records them in 'possible_paths'."""
        legal_moves = self._game.find_legal_moves()
        if not legal_moves:
            score = self._game.peg_count
            if not self.possible_paths[score]:
                self.possible_paths[score] = self._game.moves.copy()
        else:
            children = []
            for peg in legal_moves:
                for move in legal_moves[peg]:
                    children.append(Node((peg, move)))
            for child in children:
                self._game.move(*child.data)
                self._find_paths(child)
        try:
            self._game.undo()
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Peg class:

```
class Peg(RawPen):
    """A specialized 'RawPen' that represents a peg."""

    def __init__(self, start_point, graphics):
        """Initialize self. See help(type(self)) for accurate signature."""
        self.graphics = graphics
        self.possible_moves = []
        super().__init__(self.graphics.canvas, "circle", _CFG["undobuffersize"],
                     True)
        self.pen(pendown=False, speed=0, outline=2, fillcolor="red",
             pencolor="black", stretchfactor=(1.25,1.25))
        self.start_point = start_point
        self.goto(start_point)
        self.ondrag(self._remove)
        self.onrelease(self._place)

    def _remove(self, x, y):
        """Removes peg from hole if it has moves."""
        if self.possible_moves:
            self.goto(x,y)

    def _place(self, x, y):
        """Places peg in peg hole if legal."""
        if self.possible_moves:
            target_holes = [tuple(map(add, self.start_point, move)) for move in
                        self.possible_moves]
            distances = [self.distance(hole) for hole in target_holes]
            hole_distances = dict(zip(distances, target_holes))
            nearest_hole = hole_distances[min(hole_distances)]
            if self.distance(nearest_hole) <= 0.45:
                self.goto(nearest_hole)
                peg = self.graphics._subtract_offset(self.start_point)
                move = tuple(map(sub, self.pos(), self.start_point))
                move = tuple(map(int, move))
                self.graphics.game.move(peg, move)
                self.start_point = self.pos()
            else:
                self.goto(self.start_point)
```

Comment: If you can provide the code that isn't working, that would be helpful!

Comment: It's a lot of code, so I'll provide only what I assume are the most relevant parts. cx_Freeze is a godsend, by the way. I've frozen another app with it and it works like a charm. You've done very good work.

Comment: The other bugs are that the "pegs" (which are subclasses of `turtle.RawPen`), which are designed to only be able to be dragged if they can legally move, are at times not able to be moved even then. Also note that the `__init__` file changes the working directory to `data`, which contains the move shelves and my `turtle.cfg` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frozen application is going to have a different value for `__value__` then the unfrozen application. You will have to deal with that accordingly! This is a common issue that bites a lot of people. Anything that assumes that the module is found in the file system is going to stop working properly when frozen. The other gotcha is dynamic importing of modules.

The [documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) covers this and other topics that will hopefully help you out!

Comment: My `__init__` file now includes something similar to the example in the "Using data files" section of the FAQ, and that fixed part of it. The other thing I had to do was include the `dbm.dumb` module in the "includes" list, as `shelve` needs it to operate, and it wasn't automatically included in the `dbm` package. Now everything works perfectly. I appreciate it.